# What exceptions I should mention at method declaration, and which exception I should catch in my catch block?

Tags: java, exception

Lets say we have conditions like below.

A)

```
public void method() throws ... {

      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
}
```

or

B)

```
public void method(){

  try{

      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
   }catch(...){

      //doing something here
   }

}
```

Assume that line marked with `"XXXX"` is one line of code that may throw an exception(lets assume that this line will not throw an Error).

So my question is this that, what are the exceptions I should mention in first case( at method declaration) and which exception I should catch in my catch block??

* I know that just throwing and catching Exception exception is enough but I think that wont be a good design. ***

Comment: Thats what I am asking. What I should write in my catch block or at throws place???

Comment: You should write the exceptions that your method is capable of throwing... If you have an IDE like eclipse, it will show you what you need to include, or you can look at its javadoc.

Comment: General rule of thumb: only catch exceptions that your method is capable of recovering from.

Comment: @Alex, I am not really asking the concepts here. Its very simple what to write at the place of "..." :)

Comment: There's also a case to be made for wrapping a bunch of exceptions in your own exception if the caller isn't expected to handle them any differently. (I.e. it shouldn't make a difference your module failed to start up because it couldn't read a configuration file, or if it failed to start up because there was an error parsing it.) Or not. This is very much an "it depends" situation.

Comment: @JaikratSingh At the place of … in A), write the exceptions that can occur but you can't handle. At the place of … in B), write the exception type that can occur and you can handle. (Use more `catch` blocks if there's more of those without a sane common superclass. `Exception` isn't sane, unless you're just wrapping a spurious checked exception – like the ones that the reflection API throws – in an unchecked one.)

Comment: @JaikratSingh There's no single right answer. For example, you don't have to declare anything that extends RuntimeException in your throws list, but sometimes it's a good idea to (e.g. if the method is part of a public API). Similarly, you're only required to catch the most specific type of exception that can be thrown, but sometimes it's a good idea to catch Exception or even Throwable (e.g. if this is your last chance to handle an exception before the user sees it).

Comment: Yeah, Thanks @millimoose. This one helped me.

Comment: @Alex, Completely agree with you. Just putting "XXXXXXX" no one can say like what exception can this line throw. Actually, I was asked this question in an interview. So on the same I put in that way only. And was more interested in the answers :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're asking how to tell what exceptions a given method will or may throw.  That's hard to answer since you're not telling us what method(s) you're trying to run.  But part of the point of Java is that it's statically typed, and you do in fact know exactly which exceptions can be thrown by any method.  It's a compile time error not to explicitly catch any exceptions methods you call may trigger, so you'll know immediately if you're supposed to be catching something.  The exception to this is `RuntimeException` and it's children, which is intentionally not part of the compile-time contract.

Generally, `RuntimeException`s shouldn't be caught, they indicate some sort of state you shouldn't have let your program get into in the first place (like not checking for `null` triggering a `NullPointerException`) but you can check the documentation for the methods you're working with to see what they may throw.  For instance, [`String.substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) says it may throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  Usually, you should be doing the necessary index checks ahead of time, but if you can't do so in advance, you can catch it, like so:

```
int userInputWeCantTrust = -4;
try {
  System.out.println("foo".substring(userInputWeCantTrust));
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
  System.err.println("Looks like I can't trust you, user.");
}
```

When you do this, you want to be as explicit with the exception type as you can (e.g. catch `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, not `RuntimeException`), and put as little code as possible inside the `try` block.  Otherwise you risk accidentally catching exceptions you should have allowed to keep propagating.

---

Deciding to catch or throw is a design decision.  If you are able to handle a given exception, then you wrap it in a try-catch, if you aren't, you don't.

**Example One**, parsing an integer, default to `default` on failure:

```
public static int parse(String s, int default) {
  try {
    return Integer.parseInt(s);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return default;
  }
}
```

**Example Two**, parsing user input, let the main method handle error reporting:

```
// the throws note here isn't actually necessary, since NFE is a RuntimeException
public static int parse(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
  return Integer.parseInt(s);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    for(String s : args){
      System.out.println(parse(s));
    }
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.err.println("You entered an invalid number.");
  }
}
```

It really depends on your use case.

Comment: "**It really depends on your use case.**"
If you could have written this line at first there would not be any need to explain this much big.

Just kidding, nice explanation. Thanks for reply

Comment: That was what I wrote first, but your comments to other people implied you didn't want to hear about when to catch vs. throw, but what Exceptions you might ever possibly catch.  If you find people answering questions you didn't ask, take a second look at your question, you could probably revisit it and make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will answer these questions for you: you are required to catch `Exceptions` that your code can generate, **or** declare them as thrown by your method. The compiler will complain if you've missed any. `RuntimeExceptions` are the exception to this.

The only choice that you have is to catch these particular exceptions or propagate them using `throws`. This choice - which `Exceptions` are thrown and which are caught, depends on your particular goals.

You'll need to be familiar with the APIs that you're using, and part of the API is `Exceptions` thrown by the API methods, but if you miss one then your code won't compile, giving you the chance to address it.

Comment: That makes little sense. Compiler will help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

To put it briefly:

1. (a) All checked exceptions
2. (b) All handled exceptions

It's good to mark exceptions as thrown if you're not handling them as they [become part of the documentation for that method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) (e.g. JavaDocs):

> Any Exception that can be thrown by a method is part of the method's
>   public programming interface. Those who call a method must know about
>   the exceptions that a method can throw so that they can decide what to
>   do about them. These exceptions are as much a part of that method's
>   programming interface as its parameters and return value.

For your `catch` block, the main thing is to make sure that you're handling any exceptions you are catching (at the least, logging the exception message). You may want to try to recover from the exception, throw a different type of exception or just log the output:

E.g. good:

```
catch(NullPointerException e) {
    variable = "default-value";
}

catch(NullPointerException e) {
    throw new OhNoesException();
}

catch(NullPointerException e) {
    log.warn(e.getMessage());
}
```

If all you're doing is dropping the Exception though, it would be better to throw it. 
E,g, Bad (as a general rule of thumb):

```
catch(NullPointerException e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to think about what a caller expects from your method. Think of this is the 'promise' that your method gives to a caller.

Now, suppose you are calling something, and you might get an exception. The question you might ask yourself is: can I still fulfil that promise I made by handling that exception, and going on? If you can't: throw the exception on (or, alternatively, throw a different exception instead -- by wrapping it in a MyApplicationException or something).

As was written before: this can be a design question -- the 'promise' of your Integer-parsing method might be to 'turn a string into a number in the best possible way', in which case you don't throw an exception under any circumstances, or it could be 'parse a String that should be a proper encoding of an Integer'; in which case throwing the exception would be a better idea.